# Caminho para upload com variável

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou querendo usar um caminho de upload "mutável". Fiz um sistema de licitações, que a cada nova licitação, é criada uma pasta com o nome da mesma onde serão upados os arquivos relacionados a mesma utilizando mkdir(); porém agora não sei como enviar os arquivos, para a sua respectiva pasta.

[image: pic]

Quando a pessoa clica em enviar arquivo, o arquivo tinha que ir para a pasta da licitação selecionada.

Segue o meu codigo de upload de arquivos:

```
    <?php 
include ("funcoes.php");
require_once ("conexao.php");

$msg = false;
$objeto = $_POST["objeto"];
var_dump($objeto);

if( isset($_POST['enviou']) && $_POST['enviou'] == 1 ){

    // arquivo
    $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

    // Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
    $tamanhoPermitido = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb

    //Define o diretorio para onde enviaremos o arquivo
    $diretorio = "uploads/";

    // verifica se arquivo foi enviado e sem erros
    if( $arquivo['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

        // pego a extensão do arquivo
        $extensao = extensao($arquivo['name']);

        // valida a extensão
        if( in_array( $extensao, array("pdf") ) ){

            // verifica tamanho do arquivo
            if ( $arquivo['size'] > $tamanhoPermitido ){

                $msg = "<strong>Aviso!</strong> O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até ".$tamanhoPermitido/MB." MB.";
                $class = "alert-warning";

            }else{
)

                // // atribui novo nome ao arquivo
                // $novo_nome  = md5(time()).".".$extensao;

                // faz o upload
                $destino = $diretorio.$objeto."/".basename($_FILES['arquivo']);
                $enviou = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo'], $destino);

                if($enviou){
                    header("Location: listalicitacao.php");
                    die();
                }else{
                    echo "Erro ao subir arquivo";
                }
            }

        }else{
            $msg = "<strong>Erro!</strong> Somente arquivos PDF são permitidos.";
            $class = "alert-danger";
        }

    }else{
        $msg = "<strong>Atenção!</strong> Você deve enviar um arquivo.";
        $class = "alert-info";
    }
}
?>
```

HTML em que pego o nome da licitacao:

```
<?php
require_once("elementos.php");
?>
                <div class="alinha">
                <h3>Licitações</h3>
                <form action="cadastralicitacao.php" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Objeto</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="objeto" rows="4"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Modalidade</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="modalidade">
                      <option value="Pregão">Pregão</option>
                      <option value="Concorrência">Concorrência</option>
                      <option value="Carta convite">Carta convite</option>
                      <option value="Tomada de preços">Tomada de preço</option>
                      <option value="Leilão">Leilão</option>
                      <option value="Chamamento">Chamamento</option>
                      <option value="Dispensa">Dispensa</option>
                      <option value="Inexigibilidade">Inexigibilidade</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">Status do processo</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="status">
                      <option value="Em andamento">Em andamento</option>
                      <option value="Encerrado">Encerrado</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Número do processo</label>
                      <input type="text" name="numprocesso" class="form-control" placeholder="Forneça o número do processo">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Data de abertura</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dataabertura" placeholder="Forneça o número do processo">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <?php
 require_once("rodape.php");
```

O nome da licitação tá em "Objeto", porém já uso ela em outra página, na cadastralicitação.php, e eu nao sei como usar ela ná pagina de upload

Cadastralicitacao:

```
<?php

require_once("conexao.php");

$obj = $_POST["objeto"];
$mod = $_POST["modalidade"];
$sta = $_POST["status"];
$num = $_POST["numprocesso"];
$dat = $_POST["dataabertura"];

$query = "insert into licitacao (objeto, modalidade, status, numprocesso, dataabertura) values ('{$obj}','{$mod}','{$sta}','{$num}','{$dat}')";

if(mysqli_query($conexao,$query)){
    mkdir("uploads/$obj", 0777);
    header("Location: listalicitacao.php");
    die();
} else {
    echo "Erro ao adicionar licitação";
}

require_once("rodape.php");
```

Não sei como reutilizar essa variável $objeto em outras páginas

Página onde é chamado o upload de arquivos:

```
<?php
require_once ("elementos.php");
?>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="post" action="recebe_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="objeto" value="<?=$_POST["objeto"]?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="enviou" value="1">
            <label>Arquivo</label>
            <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O nome da licitação vem onde ?

Comment: <form action="cadastralicitacao.php" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Objeto</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="objeto" rows="4"></textarea>
                  </div>  É o objeto, porém já uso ele em outra página, o cadastralicitacoes.php

Comment: Tudo o que é informação relevante deve estar na pergunta. Adicione esse trecho de `html` também à pergunta indicando que o nome da licitação vem dai.